# Show duplicate rows in the table with grouping with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am using tablix in SSRS report. The report is displaying data only in the first row but when the same group has multiple rows then it doesn't show duplicate data in the other rows.

I want to repeat the data in each and every row:

[image: I want to repeat the data in each and every row]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: oh okay sure. thanks. the reason I add urgent because its quite important for my project i am working on at job and it needs to be resolved soon. I check everywhere on google and couldnt find an answer

Comment: Could you add an image of the unexpected output please?

Comment: Can you explain how your tablix is set up? It seems like all you need to do is remove the row groups. You may or may not then have to adjust the sorting to get it sorted the way it currently is, hard to say without knowing the dataset or the tablix.